# line and image after heading, auto count line width to fill up the container

Tags: jquery, html, css, line

I need to develop a heading which look something like this.[image]

The image will stay in same row with the heading, but at the end of the container. And a line cover up the gap in between which is responsive as well.

May I know am I able to do it with css?
Attached with my codepen which I fail to do so.
https://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/aboyPWY

```
<h1>Home</h1>

h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25694.svg);
  background-size:30px auto;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25694.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

I used flexbox:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.wrapper img {
  height: inherit;
}

.line {
  flex: 1 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> am I able to do it with css?

For example, with pseudo element

Result ([on CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/mdbMaKb))

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

p::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}

img {
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>HOME</p>
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25694.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="image">
</div>
```